# How to properly use class inheritance in Kotlin in combination with Kotlinx Serialization

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have a simple hierarchy containing of the following:

- *abstract* class BaseItem
- *open* class Item : BaseItem
- class Backpack : Item

They should all work with Kotlinx Serialization. It went fine until I added the `Backpack` class.
I use version `1.4.32` of Kotlinx Serialization.

Here is my class hierarchy in detail

```kotlin
// Items.kt

@Serializable
sealed class BaseItem {
    abstract val id: String
    abstract val type: ItemType
    abstract var brand: String
    abstract var model: String
    abstract var imageLink: String
    abstract var traits: MutableList<Trait>
    abstract var implicitTraits: MutableList<Trait>
    abstract var details: MutableMap<String, String>
}

@Serializable
open class Item(
    override val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    override val type: ItemType = ItemType.UNDEFINED,
    override var brand: String,
    override var model: String,
    override var imageLink: String,
    override var traits: MutableList<Trait>,
    override var implicitTraits: MutableList<Trait>,
    override var details: MutableMap<String, String>,
) : BaseItem()

@Serializable // is marked as incorrect 
class Backpack(
    brand: String,
    model: String,
    imageLink: String,
    traits: MutableList<Trait>,
    implicitTraits: MutableList<Trait>,
    details: MutableMap<String, String>,
    var volume: Int
) : Item(
    type = ItemType.BACKPACK,
    brand = brand,
    model = model,
    imageLink = imageLink,
    traits = traits,
    implicitTraits = implicitTraits,
    details = details
)
```

The IDE is showing me the following message for the `@Serialization` annotation attached to the  `Backpack` class.

```
This class is not serializable automatically because it has primary constructor parameters that are not properties
```

I was not able to find out what the working way it is to make this correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the parameters of your constructor are not defined as properties of the class. To have the parameters defined as properties you have to add `val` or `var` to the parameters. This would resolve the error message you currently have:

```
@Serializable
class Backpack(
    override var brand: String,
    override var model: String,
    override var imageLink: String,
    override var traits: MutableList<Trait>,
    override var implicitTraits: MutableList<Trait>,
    override var details: MutableMap<String, String>,
    var volume: Int
) : Item(
    type = ItemType.BACKPACK,
    brand = brand,
    model = model,
    imageLink = imageLink,
    traits = traits,
    implicitTraits = implicitTraits,
    details = details
)
```

But this would still not compile as you would end up with `Serializable class has duplicate serial name of property 'brand', either in the class itself or its supertypes` for all properties that are used in both classes. But anyhow, I am a little bit surprised by the design as it usually not a good practice to inherit from a non abstract class. Without knowing the intentions I am wondering whether sth.like this would not work for you as well:

```
sealed class BaseItem {
    abstract val id: String
    abstract val type: ItemType
    abstract var brand: String
    abstract var model: String
    abstract var imageLink: String
    abstract var traits: MutableList<Trait>
    abstract var implicitTraits: MutableList<Trait>
    abstract var details: MutableMap<String, String>
}

@Serializable
data class Item(
    override val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    override val type: ItemType = ItemType.UNDEFINED,
    override var brand: String,
    override var model: String,
    override var imageLink: String,
    override var traits: MutableList<Trait>,
    override var implicitTraits: MutableList<Trait>,
    override var details: MutableMap<String, String>,
) : BaseItem()

@Serializable
data class Backpack(
    override val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    override val type: ItemType = ItemType.BACKPACK,
    override var brand: String,
    override var model: String,
    override var imageLink: String,
    override var traits: MutableList<Trait>,
    override var implicitTraits: MutableList<Trait>,
    override var details: MutableMap<String, String>,
    override var var volume: Int
) : BaseItem()
```

I btw. removed the `@Serializable` from `BaseItem` as it is unnecessary because the class is abstract anyhow and therefore won't be serialized at all. I also made your classes `data class` because my impression was that those basically exist to hold data and those are usually implemented with `data class`. I left the many `var` I see as I don't know the reasoning for those but a small hint from my side is that you should prefer `val` over `var` especially in `data class`. A `var` in this scenario feels like a code smell to me and you might want to consider using `val` instead. A good literatur for such things is the Kotlin page itself: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#idiomatic-use-of-language-features

Answer (score 2):

From [Designing Serializable Hierarchy](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#designing-serializable-hierarchy):

> To make hierarchy of classes serializable, the properties in the parent class have to be marked abstract, making the [parent] class abstract, too.

Comment: `Items` however is not planned to be used abstract - there are instances of it in the codebase already and should stay that way

Comment: @xetra11 In that case, `BackPack` cannot extend `Item` and also be serializable. You may need to adjust your class hierarchy as suggested by Big_Foot1989.